# positioning elements in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have spent already several hours trying to correctly position several elements in a fixed bootstrap navbar, but I do not manage to have exactly what I would like. This is what I have so far:

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.aprentiko.com">brand</a>
                    <p class="navbar-text">title of the page</p>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#tocWindow" data-toggle="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#configWindow" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#helpWindow" data-toggle="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#" id="audioControl"><span id="audioInPause" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

The problems I have are the following:

- I would like to position the "title of the page" element in the middle of the screen, but it always stays in the left, next to the brand.
- The audioControl item should be independent of the other icons in the right side (i.e. it should not collapse when the viewport becomes too small. I achieved the "not collapsing" part, but when the icons collapse I get a) the play button always goes in a second row, b) clicking on the collapsed button activates the play button, instead of opening the menu to select one of the collapsed items.

I created a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/cwx1wvo7

Comment: Honestly it's probably not a good idea to do this using the Bootstrap navbar, which is easily the most inflexible component in the framework.

Comment: @MattD, which other way would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first one quickly, but I don't know if it will work with collapse, you can play around.

I agree with the comment above about by MattD. As a twist, partition your nav using col-lg-xx col-md-xx etc then use text-center

As an example to give you and idea,

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-left col-lg-10 col-md-9">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.aprentiko.com">brand
      <p class="text-center navbar-text">title of the page</p>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right col-lg-2 col-md-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in fact, u should take a look at the bootstap.css to have an idea of the classes used to code elements. 
the ms-md-auto move ur elements to the right: 

.ms-md-auto {
    margin-left: auto !important;
  }
```

`<ul class="navbar-nav ms-md-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" >`